# Auto logout after a time due to no internet connection in android

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences, logout, session-timeout

I need to implement a timer for auto logout a user if the connection with the internet is lost, I have a method to check if there is a connection, but I don't know how to do the timer. Any help will be appreciated

```
 public boolean hasConnection() {
        boolean retorno = false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            retorno = true;
        } else {
            retorno = false;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retorno;
}
```